# Rust explicit type annotation vs integer literal suffix

Tags: variables, rust, types, annotations

As we know, there are two similar ways of explicit type hints in Rust:

```
let val: i16 = 777;
// and:
let val = 777i16;
```

My questions is: what are the benefits of both of them? (Let's only look at the case of literals, not runtime values). They seem identical to me.

Comment: They are identical, just difference in the way you declare them nothing else.

Comment: @SudhirDhumal yeah, you're right. I have come up with an idea to check the generated assembly code for both cases. Identical.

Answer (score 2):

I find using the literal annotation (`777i16`) is often useful when creating an array or vector, and passing it to a function that accepts multiple types. For example

```rust
fn take_value<T>(input: Vec<T>) {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    take_value(vec![0u16; 1024]);
}
```

Otherwise I prefer the explicit annotation for readability.